# onclick div change input value

Tags: jquery, input, onclick, click

I have some divs and array of inputs when I click on div then input1:last and input2:last must get other values. Can you help me?

```
    <div class="super" onclick="changeValue(this)">60x90</div>
    <div class="super" onclick="changeValue(this)">100x150</div>
    <input name="input1[]" value="40"/>
    <input name="input2[]" value="50"/>
```

---

```
    function changeValue(o){
        if($('div.super').text() == "60x90") {
        $('input[name="input1[]"]').val('60');
        $('input[name="input2[]"]').val('90');   
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to close your name properties with end quotes. Why are you using brackets in the name properties? Also, your function is not closed. Plus, you should try if ($(o).html()=='60X90') { //... change values }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function changeValue($this)
    {
        console.log($($this).text())
        if($($this).text() == "60x90") 
        {
          $.each($($this).text().split('x'),function(key,value){
            $('input[name="input'+(key+1)+'[]"]').val(value);
           });
       }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="super" onclick="changeValue(this)">60x90</div>
    <div class="super" onclick="changeValue(this)">100x150</div>
    <input name='input1[]' value="40"/>
    <input name='input2[]' value="50"/>
```